# what is "|" operator in Go?

Tags: go

what does this `|` operator do in Go? I found this in

```
import log

log.SetFlags(log.Ldate | log.Lmicroseconds | log.Llongfile)
```

When I checked the `log.SetFlags(flag)` method, it accepts an `int`. I don't understand how does it operate on this `int` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` operator is `bitwise OR`, as mentioned in the Arithmetic operators section of [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators).

This performs bitwise `OR` of two integers. In this case, combining multiple flags into one.

In the [log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants) package, the flags have the following values:

```
const (
    Ldate         = 1 << iota     // the date in the local time zone: 2009/01/23
    Ltime                         // the time in the local time zone: 01:23:23
    Lmicroseconds                 // microsecond resolution: 01:23:23.123123.  assumes Ltime.
    Llongfile                     // full file name and line number: /a/b/c/d.go:23
    Lshortfile                    // final file name element and line number: d.go:23. overrides Llongfile
    LUTC                          // if Ldate or Ltime is set, use UTC rather than the local time zone
    Lmsgprefix                    // move the "prefix" from the beginning of the line to before the message
    LstdFlags     = Ldate | Ltime // initial values for the standard logger
)
```

- `Ldate`: 1 (or `b00001`)
- `Lmicroseconds`: 4 (or `b00100`)
- `Llongfile`: 8 (or `b01000`)

Performing a bitwise OR of all three gives you `b01101` or 13. This is a common way of using "bit flags" and combining them.

Comment: I get your answer, but how does it check that it has a certain flag?

Comment: To check if a flags is set, just do: `if val & Ldate != 0`.

Comment: thanks I get it now. btw, the flags sum is 13. `Llongfile` represents 8 i guess.

Comment: Yeah, I misread. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

`|` operator is an Arithmetic operator called `bitwise OR` used for integers operations.

Example

```
   var a uint = 60  /* 60 = 0011 1100 */  
   var b uint = 13  /* 13 = 0000 1101 */ 
   c := a | b       /* 61 = 0011 1101 */
```

Here, 
`log.Ldate` , `log.Lmicroseconds`, `log.Llongfile` all represent `int` value.
Bitwise Or of their value means `1|4|8 = 13`, so flags set as `13` which is a int value.